# Should I make a reservation for going from Rome to Florence by train?

Tags: trains, public-transport, tickets, italy, high-speed-rail

I am planning to visit Italy in December and I want to go from Rome (termini) to Florence by train. Should I book a train ticket from now or will there be available when I arrive at the termini station?

Comment: Your title's very unclear. "Should I make a reservation... by train? suggests you want us to compare to car/ plane/ bus. But you really meant "a month in advance". Don't put "now" in the title either because it'll be ephemeral. Also, when you say "in December", do you mean near Christmas/NYE? or some other December date?

Comment: My title is a title. For clarification, one has to read the question (tags also help). Also it doesn't matter whether it is in December or in July on any time. It is completely irrelevant.

Comment: a) Your question was trying to ask if advance booking was needed, but the title didn't say that. Not ask for recommendations for car/plane/ etc. I had read the question and tags twice, and it was still unclear. b) The tags didn't help identify what was specifically being asked. c) The date can well be relevant. Christmas and July/August (holiday season in Italy) are peak times. You didn't say if it was Dec 1 or Dec 24. Big difference. If you can't buy a ticket on Dec 24, you miss Christmas. Dec 1, obviously different.

Comment: @smci Should I make a reservation = book in advance. You ares wasting your time here trying to prove that the question is unclear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, if you have certainty about your time of travel, then it is advisable to purchase tickets beforehand, not so much for risk of trains selling out, but more for significant savings.

With the exception of some three regional trains a day the line between Florence and Rome is served by high-speed trains "Frecciarossa" or "Frecciargento". Tickets for those are to be had at significant discounts when booked sufficiently in advance. Have a look to the [trenitalia website](http://www.trenitalia.com/tcom-en) as well as [italo](http://www.italotreno.it/en) (competitor, less frequent trains but may be cheaper) for booking and also read what [the man in Seat61](http://www.seat61.com/Italy.htm) has to say.

That being said, unless traveling at peak times when seats will sell out, you could buy a ticket until right before departure (not sure whether even on the train, in case seek a conductor and explain). If you need flexibility you can also buy tickets with very lenient fare rules in advance, at the regular price.

Comment: I booked with the 'Italo' train and it was pretty good. We had a 20 minute delay on our trip back from Florence to Rome, but everything was very good and confortable. (and way cheaper than Trenitalia)

Comment: +1 about Italo. If you make a reservation with some time in advance, you will probably be able to get some discount on the normal price of the tickets with Italo as well

Answer (score 4):

You probably want to take a Frecciarossa/Frecciargento train, leaving about each 30min and taking about 90min.

In this case, the answer is yes, you need a reservation.

Answer (score 2):

Not if you take the regional/intercity train. In that case you can purchase your pass minutes before boarding but with no guarantee that you will find a free seat. They are the cheapest rails.

Regional journey takes double the time required for high speed rails (but those trains are still enforced severe speed limits for infrastructural reasons).

Reservation is instead *required* for high speed rails, can be purchased up to 3 minutes before scheduled departure. You won't get a pass at all if the train has no seat for you.